# Vue3 defineAsyncComponent - get props or component name during load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

is it possible within Vue.defineAsyncComponent loader fn, to know
**what props are being passed, or at least name of the element** being loaded?

```
<div id="testtpl"><loadtest :x="x"></loadtest></div>
```

and in app definition, components part is this:

```
components: {
    loadtest: Vue.defineAsyncComponent({
        loader: () =>  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // how do i get component name and/or props passed
            // for example to pass to axios request as url parameter
        }),
        loadingComponent: VueLoadingApp,
        errorComponent: VueErrorApp,
        delay: 200, // ms
        timeout: 5000
    }
)
```

Comment: You can't. You shouldn't use a loader for that, this is XY problem

Comment: @EstusFlask well i wanted to make a generic component loader - if local cached (sessionStorage) version missing or expired. Well this is dumb :( 
I expected there to be something for that, bc making multiple such components, means repeating lots of code. But thanks anyway, at least i know it realy can not be done

Comment: You need to wrap Vue.defineAsyncComponent() with a function and provide all relevant details as a param, e.g. name